# How to uninstall older version of the same software (Zoom)?

Tags: software-installation, updates, zoom-meeting

How to uninstall an older version of a software on Ubuntu? Today I had to update Zoom in order to have my online class, but now I have two icons of Zoom.

Are there two versions of Zoom installed? How do I uninstall the older one?

Answer (score 15):

You have to run two commands:

1. `dpkg -l | grep zoom`
2. `snap list | grep zoom`

and then decide which version is older.

Then remove old version with one of the commands below:

- `sudo apt-get purge zoom`
- `snap remove zoom-client`