# Uninstall extra Zoom Meeting application?

Tags: software-uninstall, zoom-meeting

Recently I seem to have "acquired" a second copy of Zoom. I cannot find it under the Software application and I cannot remove it via `snap` or `apt`. I have no idea where it came from, but it's a different Zoom UI than the version I installed, and doesn't work with my mic correctly. I can still uninstall "my" copy of the app (left in picture below).

This may have happened when I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.

How can I uninstall this unwanted application?

[image: Dual Zoom installs]

```
$ snap list | grep zoom
zoom-client           5.3.472687.1012             106    latest/stable    ogra           -

$ apt list | grep zoom
libnet-z3950-simple2zoom-perl/focal,focal 1.04-1build2 all
libnet-z3950-zoom-perl/focal 1.30-2build1 amd64
node-d3-zoom/focal,focal 1.8.3-1 all
ruby-zoom/focal 0.5.0-2 amd64
xzoom/focal 0.3-25 amd64
zoom-player/focal 1.1.5~dfsg-5 amd64
zoom/now 5.0.413237.0524 amd64 [residual-config]

$ grep -R Zoom /usr/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:application/x-zoom=Zoom.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:x-scheme-handler/callto=Zoom.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:x-scheme-handler/tel=Zoom.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:x-scheme-handler/zoommtg=Zoom.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:x-scheme-handler/zoomphonecall=Zoom.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:x-scheme-handler/zoomus=Zoom.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/gnome-universal-access-panel.desktop:Keywords=Keyboard;Mouse;a11y;Accessibility;Contrast;Cursor;Sound;Zoom;Screen;Reader;big;high;large;text;font;size;AccessX;Sticky;Keys;Slow;Bounce;Mouse;Double;click;Delay;Speed;Assist;Repeat;Blink;visual;hearing;audio;typing;
/usr/share/applications/gnome-keyboard-panel.desktop:Keywords=Shortcut;Workspace;Window;Resize;Zoom;Contrast;Input;Source;Lock;Volume;
/usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop:Name=Zoom
/usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop:Comment=Zoom Video Conference
/usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop:Icon=Zoom.png
/usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop:StartupWMClass=Zoom
/usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop:Name[en_US]=Zoom
/home/adsteel/.local/share/applications/chrome-hmbjbjdpkobdjplfobhljndfdfdipjhg-Profile_2.desktop:Name=Zoom
```

Comment: @Kulfy added output of the first two above. 3rd command had no output.

Comment: I'd suggest finding the .desktop files https://askubuntu.com/questions/217331/where-are-the-desktop-icon-files-stored for both of them so you can get more information about the command your system uses to invoke them. From there, you can have better clarity about how to uninstall.

Comment: @Kulfy snap zoom is the one I installed, that works correctly

Comment: @Kulfy I've added the output from the 3rd command you suggested.

Comment: @Kulfy whoa, it was definitely a chrome app. Very weird. I removed it from the Chrome apps and it disappeared. Thank you!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1257128/48214 helped me remove various Zoom installations.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the output of `grep -R Zoom /usr/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications`, it seems the duplicate Zoom is being provided by Chrome as a Chrome app.

To remove that, open Google Chrome and go to `chrome://apps`, right click and click on "**Remove from Chrome**".

Restart the GNOME shell if the icon still appears using:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. type `r`
3. hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This was it, thank you. Would the upgrade to 20.04 have done this?

Comment: @steel Ubuntu won't do it. I don't use Zoom but you may have hosted/joined meeting from browser which may have added a Chrome app. I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

My case is the extra zoom package was installed from ubuntu software rather than a web extension.
On my computer, i searched for `ubuntu software` then on the top section, look for the tab called `installed`. Click and from the list search for zoom-client.
Use the uninstall button to uninstall the application