# Where on earth is the Postman application on my 20.04 desktop?

Tags: package-management, uninstall

Do I have a "ghost" Postman (v.5.5.5) that can be launched, but not be removed?
[screen capture of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIPcw.png)

The app is

1. not in Ubuntu Software under "installed",
2. not found in Snap - `sudo snap list` ,
3. not locally installed as there is no trace of the name "Postman" - `sudo find / -name postman*` returns nothing,
4. Right-click on the Postman launch icon for "Show Details" yields: ""Sorry! There are no details for that application.", and
5. The Postman is not showing up as a Chrome extension or Chrome app.

I appreciate it anyone could shed some light on removing this old app.

Cheers,

Comment: As the description suggests, it is a Chrome app, which I believe is no longer maintained.

Comment: Thanks Kulfy.  I just checked the chrome settings and added item 5.

Comment: Run `grep -iR "postman" /usr/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications` and append the output in question body.

Comment: Kulfy!  Found it in one of the .desktop files, pointing to the chrome app that is no longer supported.  Thanks!!

Comment: Considering point 5 from your answer, this is strange. Did you look into `chrome://apps`? Is your issue resolved now?

Comment: Relevant Q&A: [Uninstall extra Zoom Meeting application?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1285389/816190)

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. Go to

> chrome://apps

and remove it.
I had checked initially in my work profile. We should check in all profiles and remove it.

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking to remove it for a long time. Finally, I got my answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded package v. 9.14.0, linux-5.13.0-40-generic was installed to home/user/Postman and home/user/.config/Postman.[How to neatly uninstall app on Linux?](https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-neatly-uninstall-app-on-linux/3075/2)